# Google Sheet: If word is in a cell then return this word in another cell

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, return-value

i did already several google-sessions and watched some youtube videos but it seems i just cant find the formula im Looking for

for example:

I have several words in different cells:
A1: car
A2: big
A3: flower
A4: nope

I have a text in cell **B1** like "the flowers are pretty today"

In cell C1 the formula I want should  only show the word from all the words A1:A4 which was found in B1 (my data is in a way that its not possible that two or more words from A1:A4 appear in B1, only one)

not- case sensitive, with wildcards

How would that look like?

some REGEXMATCH or SEARCH function??

I would be so happy if anyone could help me with that, Thanks!

The formulas i found only returned 0,1 or TRUE, false, but i need the actual word returned

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=CONCATENATE(MAP(A1:A4,LAMBDA(w,IF(REGEXMATCH(B1,"(?i)"&w),w,""))))
```